# Adding/resizing a background image to centralWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt. I searched for my question on multiple sites, but I couldn't find an answer. How can I add an image to centralWidget?

I tried:

```
MainWindow w;
w.centralWidget()->setStyleSheet("image: url(image)");
```

it worked fine but the image isn't stretched for the entire window/widget. How can I resize the image through `setStyleSheet`?

I want to display an image in the background and not the gray color, when the application opens. I tried changing the color. That worked, but it doesn't look good with buttons and labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stretch for the entire widget use `background-image`, but I'm guessing what you probably want is an image that expands in one direction, either vertically or horizontally, in that case use `background-position` to fix it to one of the borders of your widget:

```
image: url(:/path/to/image);
background-position: bottom left;
```